# How to hide the toogle editor from the tinymce editor

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

My XML is as shown below. Everything except the toogle editor button becomes hidden from the editor. Is there any other code to fix the problem.

```
<field name="description"
    type="editor"
    cols="20"
    label="COM_TEST_DESCRIPTION_LBL"
    description="COM_TEST_DESCRIPTION_DESC"
    class="inputbox"
    filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
    buttons="true"
    hide="readmore,pagebreak,image,article,toogle editor"
/>
```

Comment: Is there any options to hide the toogle editor using any hide options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use CSS styling to disable the visibility of this button:

```
.toggle-editor {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: In the editor, readmore,pagebreak,image,article are used as editors-xtn plugins , so they can hide. But the toogle editor is not used as plugin, so there is no option to edit.