# How to remove "Text mode" Button of TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

Can anybody give me a hint, how to remove that "Text Mode" button of TinyMCE?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a soltion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138275/how-to-hide-the-toogle-editor-from-the-tinymce-editor) - just disabling the button in css:

```
.toggle-editor {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/toggle_editor.php

The code used is:

```
toggleEditor('content')
```

If you want the editor mode to be toggled based on the option chose by the user from another page, you can execute (or not to) the above function on page load.

There are links to other examples on that page which you might find useful too.

Comment: No, I just wanted to remove the button visually. Thank you for your effort, I found a solution myself.