# Configure TinyMCE in Joomla front-end

Tags: joomla3.0, tinymce-4

I am having difficulty fine-tuning TinyMCE editor in a custom component in Joomla! v. 3.4 Front-end and would appreciate any advice to set it up. I am loading this editor through XML in model's "forms" folder. As seen in my picture, I have marked a portion of it with red rectangle.
Is there any setting for editor form field to omit the red marked portion?
Furthermore, is it possible to omit the "Toggle Editor" button in the bottom of the editor?
Thanks in advance.

Screenshot: http://screenshot.net/vdnx3s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option allows you to configure the menus you want to appear in the menu bar.

Disable all menus

```
tinymce.init({
    menubar : false
});
```

for "toggle editor" button look for link 
[remove toggle editor button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138275/how-to-hide-the-toogle-editor-from-the-tinymce-editor)

Comment: "tinyMCE.init" works well if I hack the core Joomla file. I tried to override "tinyMCE.init" using this code "<script type="text/javascript"> tinyMCE.init({ menubar: false }); </script>", which actually did not work. Can you please give me any further hint if "tinyMCE.init" can be overridden? BTW, "Toggle editor" works like a charm.